# Huge array of libSDL textures

Tags: c, image, caching, sdl

I am developing an app that presents the user with a potentially very large user-generated image gallery, 10 or so images at the time.
The app is to be implemented in C using libSDL and 2D textures for accelerated rendering.
The overall gist of it in pseudocode is:

```
while cycle < MAX_CYCLES
    while i < MAX_STEPS
        show a gallery of 10 image thumbnails
        while (poll events)
            if event == user has pushed next
            break
        i++
    scramble image galleries using a genetic algorithm
    cycle++
```

I could load every image from disk at initialization time, creating all the required textures, so image presentation is fast. But of course this would be slow and potentially allocate a huge array of textures.

I will scale down the images for presentation, so this could mitigate the problem, but the total size of the collection depends on user preference. Surely I can cap the maximum value, but it cannot be small.

I was thinking about unloading every unused image at every step of every cycle, using `SDL_FreeSurface` and `SDL_DestroyTexture`. This would mean reloading the data from disk, recreating the surface and recreating the texture each time. Is this a viable approach?

Also I understand that SDL textures are stored in GPU memory, so the amount of available memory on the card should be my main concern. Am I right?

In summary, is there a recommended method to deal with this type of situation?

Comment: When is the last time you scrolled to the 3rd page of a list, especially of images? Every time I see "potentially very large amount of ...", it usually just means you didn't actually think of your use cases and are throwing completely arbitrary numbers trying to look/feel important.

Comment: Not really. The whole point of the app, that for now is of my use, is to select a directory full of images and working with it. The bigger the better. I didn't fully clarify the purpose, but it is meant to be an aid in creativity, not an utility program. This may sound vague but the bottom line is that it is a requirement to have a large pool of images. It would be meaningless otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep always 3 slides in memory.

Prev - Current - Next

While presenting the current slide, preload the next slide and unload the slide no (Current - 2).

> Also I understand that SDL textures are stored in GPU memory, so the amount of available memory on the card should be my main concern. Am I right?

Not quite, if the GPU (Driver) seems it necessary, it will outsource unused texture data to RAM.

For Example, if you're presenting 10 Images and thus have 30 Images present in memory, then for 2K (with alpha) (1920 x 1080 x 4) you will need approx. 250 MB.

As long as you don't run on an embedded system (or very old, outdated system), this shouldn't be a big concern.

Comment: Interesting idea. I was adopting an all or nothing mindset, but your solution works fine for navigating forward and backward without requiring to allocate too much memory.

Comment: It is a tradeoff. Either you heat up your CPU or your GPU or fill up your memory. It is always best to distribute the load evenly to all components of your system.

Comment: I don't think it is a tradeoff, rather the only sane solution. No one wants to wait multiple minutes for program to load thousands of images if it only shows tens at a time.